# Android raw folder conflicts

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am making an audio app which play the pre loaded audio file on the raw folder.
inside the folder i am have 2 type of files.

1. mp3 files
2. a text file list all the name for the mp3 files.

This is the adapter code:

```
public ArrayList<SongInfo> getAllSong(Context context) {

    ArrayList<SongInfo> listSong = new ArrayList<SongInfo>();

    RingtonesSharedPreferences pref = new RingtonesSharedPreferences(
            context);

    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
        SongInfo info = new SongInfo();
        try {
            String name = fields[i].getName();

            if (!name.equals("ringtones")) {

                info.setFileName(name + ".mp3");
                info.setFavorite(pref.getString(info.getFileName()));
                int audioResource = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(name);
                info.setAudioResource(audioResource);
            }
            // info.setName(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("LOG", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        listSong.add(info);
    }

    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.zringlist);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));

    try {
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            listSong.get(i).setName(line);
            i++;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {

        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return listSong;
}
```

The problem happen when I am using google service which already have a file name called"gtm_analytics" inside the raw folder of that module.

My code also read that folder too and it's show up the gtm_analytics on the result and make my app crash everytime i am trying to play that.

Any one please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Don't iterate over `R.raw`. Instead, have something else (e.g., `string-array` resource) that lists your names. Or, have a blacklist of ones to ignore, and put `gtm_analytics` in that blacklist.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, I am very appreciate your answer, I am a beginner, could you please tell me in detail how to do that? I am prefer the solution that ignore the gtm_analytics one.

Comment: I have tried to change this:if (!name.equals("ringtones")) to if (!name.equals("gtm_analytics")) but the result still the same.